# How to fix photoshop ui issue on high DPI windows

Tags: photoshop

I'm having trouble with the UI of my Photoshop that i just installed, when i launch the app its all fine but the when i create new image everything is messed up. I don't know what to do with this.

Please refer to the attached image.

PS OK after opening.
[image: PS OK after opening.]

PS Messed after creating New Image/Inserting Image.
[image: PS Messed after creating New Image/Inserting Image.]

Your help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi ardie, note that stackoverflow is for programming questions, that one was probably for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been solved by re-installing the application. Maybe some components was not properly installed that's why it behaved like that.

Thank you!

Till Next time.

Comment: Before re-installing, it's often worth it to reset preferences. This often solves problems like this